# How to iterate over a list value of a dictionary in django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I have a dictionary where value are in list

```
{
    'Fees': ['88000', '88000'],
    'ROll Number': ['I0', 'I1'],
    'Mark': [10, 10]
}
```

So I am trying to insert this data in table, SO my Django template are

```
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
        {% for k, v in loan_bank_info.items %}
            <th>{{ k }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      {% for k, value in loan_bank_info.items %}
        {% for v in value %}  
          <td>{{ v }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

but in table value are printing as follow,

```
  Fees          ROll Number     Mark
  88000 88000    I0 I1           10 10
```

But what I want is -

```
Fees            ROll Number     Mark
  88000          I0             10 
  88000          I1             10
```

how to iterate over list value in Django template

Comment: I think you need the `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags to be within the outer `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over the list. Something like below

```
<tr>
      {% for k, value in loan_bank_info.items %}
        {% for v in value %}
            {% for i in v %} 
              <td>{{ i }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
```

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: That's what they were already doing. Adding another level of iteration is now going to try iterating the integer values themselves. I can't test but I think the issue is at least partly due to `<tr>` being outside of the outermost loop, but there's no reason for another inner loop from what the OP already had